# flutter dart generic type comparison not properly working

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

i create function to check generic type and call there **fromJson** function and return object
but it working some model classes and some one are not. i have no idea to fix this problem. please help sort out this issue.

this is comparison class and function

T is Generic type and T come with item type but it not going into if statement

```
class Common {
  static T genaricFormJosn<T>(dynamic e) {
    T obj;
// this T== item conditions is always false, I check in Debug mode T is type Item
    if (T == Item) {
      obj = Item.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>) as T;
    } else if (T == Stock) {
      obj = Stock.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>) as T;
    } else if (T == User) {
      obj = User.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>) as T;
    } else if (T == Person) {
      obj = Person.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>) as T;
    } else if (T == PersonCredit) {
      obj = PersonCredit.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>) as T;
    } else if (T == UOM) {
      obj = UOM.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>) as T;
    } else if (T == ItemCategory) {
      obj = ItemCategory.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>) as T;
    } else if (T == Item) {
      obj = Item.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>) as T;
    }

    return obj;
  }
}
```

this model class use **genaricFormJosn** function

```
class RequestResult<Y> {
  final List<Y> result;
  final int apiStatus;
  final String apiNote;
  final RqException ex;

  RequestResult({
    this.result,
    this.apiStatus,
    this.apiNote,
    this.ex,
  });

  factory RequestResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  

    return RequestResult(
      result: (json['result'] as List)
          ?.map((e) => e == null ? null : Common.genaricFormJosn<Y>(e))
          ?.toList(),
      apiStatus: json['apiStatus'],
      apiNote: json['apiNote'],
      ex: json['ex'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'result': this.result,
        'apiStatus': this.apiStatus,
        'apiNote': this.apiNote,
        'ex': this.ex,
      };
}

class RqException {
  final String errorMassage;
  final String stacktrace;
  RqException({
    this.errorMassage,
    this.stacktrace,
  });

  factory RqException.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return RqException(
      errorMassage: json['error'],
      stacktrace: json['stacktrace'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'error': this.errorMassage,
        'stacktrace': this.stacktrace,
      };
}
```

this model class can not find in **genaricFormJosn** function

```
class Item {
  final int id;
  final int itemID;
  final String itemName;
  final String itemCode;
  final String barcode;
  final String itemEngSpel;
  final String brand;
  final String model;
  final int itemCategoryID;
  final int binCardLocationID;
  final int overFlowLocationID;
  final String itemCategory;
  final String description;
  final double minQTY;
  final double maxQTY;
  final double itemCost;
  final int uomID;
  final String uom;
  final bool isPricingCost;
  final bool itemDiscount;
  // final List<Item> itemList;

  Item({
    this.id,
    this.itemID,
    this.itemName,
    this.itemCode,
    this.barcode,
    this.itemEngSpel,
    this.brand,
    this.model,
    this.itemCategoryID,
    this.binCardLocationID,
    this.overFlowLocationID,
    this.itemCategory,
    this.description,
    this.minQTY,
    this.maxQTY,
    this.itemCost,
    this.uomID,
    this.uom,
    this.isPricingCost,
    this.itemDiscount,
      });

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Item(
      id: json['id'],
      itemID: json['itemID'],
      itemName: json['itemName'],
      itemCode: json['itemCode'],
      barcode: json['barCode'],
      itemEngSpel: json['itemEngSpel'],
      brand: json['brand'],
      model: json['model'],
      itemCategoryID: json['itemCategoryID'],
      binCardLocationID: json['binCardLocationID'],
      overFlowLocationID: json['overFlowLocationID'],
      itemCategory: json['itemCategory'],
      description: json['description'],
      minQTY: json['minQTY'],
      maxQTY: json['maxQTY'],
      itemCost: json['itemCost'],
      uomID: json['uomid'],
      uom: json['uom'],
      isPricingCost: (json['isPricingCost'] == 1 ? true : false),
      itemDiscount: (json['itemDiscount'] == 1 ? true : false),
          );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': this.id,
        'itemID': this.itemID,
        'itemCode': this.itemCode,
        'itemName': this.itemName,
        'itemEmgSpel': this.itemEngSpel,
        'barCode': this.barcode,
        'brand': this.brand,
        'model': this.model,
        'itemCategoryID': this.itemCategoryID,
        'itemCategory': this.itemCategory,
        'description': this.description,
        'minQTY': this.minQTY,
        'maxQTY': this.maxQTY,
        'binCardLocationID': this.binCardLocationID,
        'overFlowLocationID': this.overFlowLocationID,
        'itemCost': this.itemCost,
        'uomid': this.uomID,
        'uom': this.uom,
        'isPricingCost': this.isPricingCost,
        'itemDiscount': this.itemDiscount,
        
      };
}
```

Comment: Maybe the response structure does not fit some of your models? Could you provide some more context with a specific response structure/code/error?

Comment: this code used to connect and get api data in http request.
http response json is type of RequestResult model class.
RequestResult  has result property catch to list of items.

in my case cannot bind josn item result with item model  it retun null object array 
if generic type catch it is a item type then correctly return item array

Comment: That's why I am asking - interesting, what's the structure of this result item object you can't map.

Comment: T is Generic type and Generic come with item type
but  it not going into if statement 

``` if (T == Item) {
        obj = Item.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>) as T;```

Comment: i have anther model call itemCategory and UOM. they are work correctly

Answer (score 0):

i sold out this problem.

issue come with class import statement

in common class i used this line

```
import 'package:project/data_model/item.dart';
```

and in other class i used this line

```
import 'package:project/data_model/Item.dart';
```

i change all lines to

```
import 'package:project/data_model/item.dart';
```

but i don't know why it didn't out any exception

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {
 print(Common.genaricFormJosn<User>({}));
 print(Common.genaricFormJosn<Item>({}));
 print(Common.genaricFormJosn<Stock>({}));
}
class Common<T> {
  static T? genaricFormJosn<T>(dynamic e) {  
    T? obj;
    if (T == Item) {
      print('item');     
      obj = (Item() as T);
    } else if (T == Stock) {
      print('stock');
      obj = Stock() as T;
    } else if (T == User) {
      print('user');
      obj = User() as T;
    }
    return obj;
  }
}

class Item {}
class Stock {}
class User {}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information? I edited code to above, It worked fine in dartPad, I use your code.

Comment: thank you for your help! I found the issue

Comment: thank you for your help! 
I found the issue

import 'package:smartpos/data_model/item.dart'; 
This Line I use In Common Class to import item model and 

import 'package:smartpos/data_model/Item.dart';
this line use in My API Connection Class that is the reason  get that issue. 
on API Connection Class i import Item.dart  using Capital 'I' Common Class Import statement use simple 'i' change all itme in simple case problem sold ;)